# ExpressionEngine Custom mysql field

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, expressionengine

When user in the front-end clicks on the button `#bbb` as per the jQuery code below, i want to save the value of var x into the database for the user in a a custom field called 'test'. I'm still learning EE. How do we create a custom field and and save content to it.

```
$('#bbb').click(function(){
  var x = 'some content';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this. Makes things super easy:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/external-entries/

Comment: thanks for the link +1, this may be what i need, but how do i create custom fields so users can save data to them. Can database tables and fields be created in EE cpanel. Or do i have to manually do this in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Yeah - if you want users to be able to submit data via the front end, without writing custom code, you should either use this: http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/freeform/ - or custom member fields as mahalie mentioned below. With either one of these, you would no longer need external entries to enter data. The other thing you can do is just create the tables in php myadmin, then set up a form - and have jquery store the form field data in variables, and use external entries to submit the data.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably add custom field for a user by creating a custom member field.
http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/cp/members/custom_member_fields_edit.html

Then you have to find that field in mySQL so you know how to write to it, I'm not sure if columns get tacked on to the exp_members table or if there's another but I'm sure you could find it using phpMyAdmin.

You'll need to update the db using your click function. (This has nothing to do with EE). Simple example: http://perfectwebtutorials.com/2011/write-and-delete-data-in-mysql-with-jquery-and-php/

Comment: If i manually created a new table with custom fields in it, how do we make a relationship between the table and the logged in user in EE.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd do that, since EE can manage the relationship for you. If you want to do it yourself, you'll have to literally do it yourself and create and use SQL joins to connect the user id to your custom table.